# Read Sequence Diagram from XMI using EMF

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram, eclipse-emf, xmi

I searched a lot about reading UML diagrams from XMI using EMF Java
 Eclipse. I only found solutions to read class diagram but my task is
to read Sequence diagram from XMI. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: may be be more precise, do you want to import a model containing (among others) interaction(s) or to read the graphical definition of a sequence diagram through an UML diagram interchange file ?

Comment: yes i want to read model nested with another transactions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After a hectic efforts finally I found a working solution, You only need to put path of error-free UML diagram in the main class, Provided code will read all nodes and sub-nodes respectively. You can customize the code as per your requirements. This code can be used both for class diagram as well as sequence diagram.*

### Sequence Diagram Model Reader (Main Class)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     MododelLoader umlModel= new ModelLoader();
    // sequence diagram XMI
     String umlFilePath = "SequenceDiagramUML\\sequenceDiagram.uml"; 

        String uri = null;
        try {
            uri = umlModel.getFileURI(umlFilePath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Object objModel = umlModel.loadModel(uri);
        Model sourceModel;
        EList<PackageableElement> sourcePackagedElements = null;
        if (objModel instanceof Model) {
            sourceModel = (Model) objModel;
            sourcePackagedElements = sourceModel.getPackagedElements();
        } else if (objModel instanceof Package) {
            Package sourcePackage = (Package) objModel;
            sourcePackagedElements = sourcePackage.getPackagedElements();
        }
        for (PackageableElement element : sourcePackagedElements){
            //for nested package
            if(element.eClass() == UMLPackage.Literals.PACKAGE){
                org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Package nestedPackage = 
             (org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Package) element;
                EList<PackageableElement> nestedPackagedElements = 
           nestedPackage.getPackagedElements();
                for (PackageableElement nestedElement : nestedPackagedElements){
                    printModelDetails(nestedElement);
                }
            }
            else
                printModelDetails(element);
        }
```

### Model Details Extractor (Helper Class)

```
 private static void printModelDetails(PackageableElement element){

    int counterEnd=1;
    String classfierName="Test";
    boolean isClass=false;
    if(element.eClass()==UMLPackage.Literals.COLLABORATION){
        Collaboration collab=(Collaboration)element;
        System.out.println("Collaboration Name: "+collab.getName());
        EList<Behavior> behaviours = collab.getOwnedBehaviors();    

        System.out.println("Behavious: ");
        if(!behaviours.isEmpty()){
            for (Behavior obj: behaviours)
            {
                Interaction interaction=(Interaction)obj;
                EList<Lifeline> lifelines=interaction.getLifelines();
                EList<InteractionFragment> fragments=interaction.getFragments();
                EList<Message> messages=interaction.getMessages();

                if(!lifelines.isEmpty()) {

                    for(Lifeline lifln:lifelines) {

                EList<EAnnotation> inter=lifln.getEAnnotations();  
                  }
                }
               if(!fragments.isEmpty()) {

                    for(InteractionFragment frag:fragments) {

                    EList<Element> elements=    frag.getOwnedElements();                    
                    }
                }
               if(!messages.isEmpty()) {

                    for(Message msg:messages) {
                        EList<ConnectorEnd> 
   connectorEnds=msg.getConnector().getEnds();
                        String conEnd1=connectorEnds.get(0).getRole().getName();
                        String conEnd2=connectorEnds.get(1).getRole().getName();
                        System.out.println("Messages: "+msg.getName());

           System.out.println("Message_Receive_event:"+msg.getMessageSort());  

                        System.out.println("ConEnd1:  "+conEnd1);
                        System.out.println("ConEnd2:  "+conEnd2);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Interaction Name: "+obj.getName());
                EList<Connector> connectors = obj.getOwnedConnectors(); 
                System.out.println("Connectors: ");
                if(!connectors.isEmpty()){
                    for (Connector behav: connectors)
                    {           

                        EList<ConnectorEnd> property = behav.getEnds(); 
                        if(!property.isEmpty()) {

                            System.out.println("Connector Ends "+counterEnd);
                            for(ConnectorEnd ends:property) {


                     System.out.println("EndName:"+ends.getRole().getName());
                            }
                            counterEnd++;
                        }
                    }       
                }
```

### ModelLoader Class (Helper Class)

```
public class ModelLoader {
     private final ResourceSet RESOURCE_SET;
      public ModelLoader() {
      RESOURCE_SET = new ResourceSetImpl();
    }

/**
 * A method that converts input path to uri and return uri.
 * 
 * @param path
 * @return uri
 * @throws Exception
 */
public String getFileURI(String path) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(path);
    String uri = f.toURI().toString();
    return uri; 
}
/**
 * A method that loads UML/Ecore model from input URI.
 * 
 * @param uri:String
 * @return model:Object
 */
public Object loadModel(String uri){
    URI modelUri = URI.createURI(uri);
    registerPackages(RESOURCE_SET);
    registerResourceFactories();
    String relPath = null;
    try {
        relPath = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    URIConverter.URI_MAP.put(URI.createURI("platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.uml2.uml/"), 
             URI.createURI("jar:file:"+
              relPath+"/EMF_Lib/org.eclipse.uml2.uml_3.1.2.v201010261927.jar! /"));
    Resource resource = null;
    try {   
        resource = RESOURCE_SET.getResource(modelUri, true);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Object result;

    Model _model = (Model) EcoreUtil.getObjectByType(resource.getContents(), 
    UMLPackage.Literals.MODEL);
    result = _model;
    // org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Package _model =
    // 
      (org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Package)EcoreUtil.getObjectByType(resource.getContents(),
    // UMLPackage.Literals.PACKAGE);
    if (_model == null) {
        result = resource.getContents().get(0);         
    }
    return result;
    }   

public void loadResources(){
    registerPackages(RESOURCE_SET);
    registerResourceFactories();
    String relPath = null;
    try {
        relPath = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    URIConverter.URI_MAP.put(URI.createURI("platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.uml2.uml/"), 


         URI.createURI("jar:file:"+
       relPath+"/EMF_Lib/org.eclipse.uml2.uml_3.1.2.v201010261927.jar!/"));
    }

     private void registerResourceFactories() 
  {
    Map extensionFactoryMap = 
      Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap();         
    extensionFactoryMap.put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, 
      UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);         
    extensionFactoryMap.put(Ecore2XMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, 
       Ecore2XMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);      
    extensionFactoryMap.put(UML22UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, 
  UML22UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);                
    extensionFactoryMap.put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, 
  UML22UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);
    extensionFactoryMap.put(UMLResource.FILE_EXTENSION, 
     UML22UMLResource.Factory.INSTANCE);        
    extensionFactoryMap.put(Resource.Factory.Registry.DEFAULT_EXTENSION,new 
   XMIResourceFactoryImpl());
    }

    private void registerPackages(ResourceSet resourceSet) 
     {
    Map packageRegistry = resourceSet.getPackageRegistry();
    packageRegistry.put(EcorePackage.eNS_URI, EcorePackage.eINSTANCE);
    packageRegistry.put(Ecore2XMLPackage.eNS_URI, Ecore2XMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
    packageRegistry.put(UMLPackage.eNS_URI, UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
    packageRegistry .put(UML212UMLResource.UML_METAMODEL_NS_URI, 
  UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
    //for RSA

   packageRegistry.put("http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/2.0.0/UML",UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
    //for Papyrus

   packageRegistry.put("http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML",UMLPackage.eINSTANCE);
    }
     }
```